# How to change Flutter TextField border color on focus?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I created a simple text field with input decoration and `Outlineboraderinput`. When I type on that text field I want to change the border color. Below link, you can see my work. What I want is change that blue border to white:

[image]

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: "Resevior Name",
    fillColor: Colors.white,
    enabledBorder:OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 2.0),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
      ),
    ),
  )
```

Comment: Set the `focusedBorder` property of your `InputDecpration`.

Comment: it worked. highly appreciated

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Add focusBorder insted of enabledBorder

```
TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: "Resevior Name",
          fillColor: Colors.white,
          focusedBorder:OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 2.0),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
          ),
        ),
      )
```

Comment: Code itself is quite self-explanatory

Comment: Hey how I increase the height of this outline like for multiline

Comment: @Noobdeveloper, you can use the "maxLines" property of  TextFormField.

Answer (score 11):

In Flutter 2.5, you can change the focus color of the `TextField` directly in the `ThemeData`:

```
theme: ThemeData().copyWith(
  // change the focus border color of the TextField
  colorScheme: ThemeData().colorScheme.copyWith(primary: Colors.amber),
  // change the focus border color when the errorText is set
  errorColor: Colors.purple,
),
```

### [Live Demo](https://dartpad.dev/?id=abd751aed0aa089c219ae4767af5b62d&null_safety=true)