# How modify the highlight color of TextField when tapped ? (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to change my labelText color when focused. I can change the text color but not when focused. In the screenshots below, the string "Email" remains blue when focused.

This is what I have:

```
Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 600),
  child: TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
      labelText: 'Email',
      suffix: Icon(
        Icons.check,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

This is what the button looks like before it's pressed.

[image]

When it's pressed, it looks like this

[image]

How can I modify these highlights to be black instead of light blue? Thanks!

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56411859/9661936) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56846793/9661936)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways you can modify the TextField's highlight color:

1. Use `InputDecoration` (do this if you want to locally modify a single `TextField`)

```dart
Container(
  child: TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
      ),
      labelText: 'Email',
      labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      suffix: Icon(
        Icons.check,
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

2. Config the `theme` property of the `MaterialApp` widget (do this if you want to set a common theme across all `TextField` widgets):

```dart
MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
          inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
        focusedBorder:
            UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black)),
        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      ),
   ),
   home: SomeScreen(),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your inputDecoration labelStyle:

```
InputDecorationTheme(
      labelStyle: TextStyle(
    color: black,
    fontSize: 12,
  );
```